# Javascript Alert ruining the layout of my asp.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I know there is a similar question, but that answer did not solve my problem.

This is how my application looks normally:

[image]

And this is how it looks after a Javascript alert (width of menu items gets screwed, the purple bar on the left has an extra part added to it on top):

[image]

This is the code I am using to call an alert:

```
    private void Alert(string msg)
    {
        Response.Write("<script language = 'javascript'>window.alert('" + msg + "')</script>");
    }
```

Did anyone ever had this problem, I had something similar even with the default asp.NET design. How can I fix this? I am using IE 7 by the way, it's ok on Firefox.

Update:

Fixed the issue with the purple bar, removed a margin. Still figuring out the menu width issue.

This is my CSS:

```
#menu
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 78%;
   top: 108px;
   width: 170px !important;  
}

div.menu
{
   padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
   background-color: #FFF; /*680840*/
   border: 1px #4e667d solid;
   height: 20px;
   width: 140px;
   color: #000; /*FFF*/
   display: block;
   line-height: 1.35em;
   padding: 4px 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
   white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
   background-color: #680840;
   color: #FFF;
   text-decoration: none;
}

.selectedMenu
{
   background-color: #680840;
   color: #FFF;
   text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
   background-color: #680840;
   color: #cfdbe6;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Update For @Sassyboy :

Front-End:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField Value="" ID="errorMessageHidden" runat="server"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var alertMsg = document.getElementById('errorMessageHidden'); 
        if (alertMsg != null) alert(alertMsg); 
    </script>
```

and c# I add this:

```
errorMessageHidden.Value = "Failed to Select - Test";
```

Comment: Looks like white space (or something else) in the header is affecting the whole page. Could you include a bit more context, maybe in a JS fiddle or link to the demo?

Comment: Having elements above the `<html>` or DTD declaration gives undefined behavior, and that's what you are getting. How about not inserting elements into the beginning of the Response stream.

Comment: @Matt - Sry there is no link for the page, and cannot use JS Fiddle, since the page itself is fine, when the Alert method is called from my C# file it is kind of generating the problem.

Comment: @Justing M. Keyes - How can I call the Alert method, and insert it after the <html> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response.Write will add to response before the HTML of the page and this leads to issues similar to what you mentioned.

There are multiple other ways in which the functionality you are trying to achieve can be achieved. e.g. you could have a hidden field hdnAlertMessage and set its value with the message you want to alert. And then check on the client side if the hidden field has a value then alert that value.

So on your server side

```
hdnAlertMessage.Value = message;
```

And on your client side

```
var alertMsg = document.getElementById('hdnAlertMessage');

if (alertMsg != null)
    alert(alertMsg.value);
```

Or something along those lines.

Edited: alert(alertMsg) to alert(alertMsg.value)

Comment: Can Javascript getElements from C# Code? Therefore if I wanted to get a string hdnAlertMessage, what exactly would I need to do with it?

Comment: You could use a server control asp:HiddenField and set its value in C# code as shown above. And then on the client side you could wrtie javascript which acts on elements rendered and available in the DOM.

Comment: please view my updated version in the description above, still not working, no alert popped up, please correct any mistakes i am doing

Comment: Since you are using Master Page, the ID rendered on the client will be a bit different from errorMessageHidden. It may be something like MainContent_errorMessageHidden. You can check that by right clicking and selecting View Source of the page. Use that Id in document.getElementById. Also finally the alert should be alertMsg.value. See my edit.

Comment: that worked mate, was MainContent_errorMessageHidden as you said.

Answer (score 3):

This is becuase Response.Write often is rendered before the HTML of the page - look at the source of your page.

There are better ways of adding Javascript to the page, look up `ClientScriptManager`.

Comment: I will definately use your approach next time thats why the up vote. However for a quick fix, sassboy's approach was very useful withouth having to change a large part of the code.